# UK Visa application for conference - Self employed

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am self employed and my Company is sponsoring my trip to attend a Business Conference in London; I have a good personal bank statement that meets the standard - regular income and savings. My concern is that my company has irregular cash flows, does this really matter? money doesn't stay in the account for too long. I believe that company's invest funds most of the time and may not have huge balances over on the short run, however the closing balance on the Company's bank statement is sufficient with over 6500GBP. of which my trip to the UK will cost about 2000GBP only.

Comment: Include the company’s trading / profit & loss accounts, and evidence of your own income from the business plus your latest tax returns. The ECO may not view the company’s money as yours, despite you being self-employed - for example, there may be outstanding creditors. So showing the business is sufficiently profitable is critical IMHO. Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: When you say "My company is sponsoring me" do you mean a company you own, or the company you work for?

Comment: I mean I'm Self employed...

Comment: So then what company is doing the sponsoring?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the irregular cash flow could be a cause for concern. But, I would still say you have a fair chance of getting the visa because they look for many different factors when making a decision:

1. **Reason to return**: Your company is probably a valid reason for return. Make sure you provide documentation to prove your company is genuine.
2. **Funds**: As you state, you have sufficient funds, but it is better if you have them in your personal bank account.
3. **Travel history**: If you have any, it is a positive factor, but you have not provided this information in your question.

Comment: Whether the company is viewed as a credible reason to return is likely to depend on what the business is (internet-based selling, for example, can be done from anywhere), how long it’s been established, how profitable it is, how many employees etc. The OP doesn’t state their citizenship but for example a self-employed national of a country viewed as high risk from an immigration perspective would ideally be able to show other ties such as property and/or family.